# Como puedo Modificar una lista que esta compuesta por objetos de una clase

Tags: python

Hola amigos estoy tratado de poder modificar el contenido una variable especifica, que esta dentro de un objeto en una lista, por medio del index puedo obtener la posición del objeto en la lista, pero como puedo hacer para modificar específicamente el contenido de una de las variables de tal objeto por ejemplo:
tengo la clase:

```
 class Paciente:
        def __init__(self, cod, name, lastname, dni, bornDate):
            self.codigo = cod
            self.nombre = name
            self.apellido = lastname
            self.cedula = dni
            self.FechaNacimiento = bornDate
```

A continuacion algo de lo que estoy intentando hacer esta la parte del codigo que trato de resolver en donde pido que el usuario ingrese un campo del objeto que desea modificar, una vez encuentra el objeto dentro de la lista, deseo modificar la variable  "Nombre" de ese objeto que se encuentra en la posición n

```
if(menu == 3):
        encontrado = False
        ced = input("Ingrese Cedula a Consultar del paciente: ")
        for e in lst:
            if(ced == e.cedula):
                encontrado = True
                ind = lst.index(e)
                break

        if (encontrado):
            mod = int(input("Escriba 1 si desea modificar este elemento: "))
            if (mod == 1):
                objPaciente = Paciente(0,"","","","",)
                objPaciente.nombre = input("ingrese Nuevo Nombre: ")
                lst.insert(e, aquí no sé que hacer?????)
```

Apreciaría mucho de su ayuda
Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es modificar un objeto no tienes que crear uno nuevo e insertarlo en la lista, simplemente modifica el atributo del que tienes. Para obtener el índice es más eficiente si haces:

```
for índice, paciente in enumerate(lst):
    if cedula == paciente.cedula:
        break
```

Esto evita recorrer la lista dos veces.

No obstante ni siquiera necesitas el índice, basta con que uses la referencia del objeto que retorna el ciclo `for`:

```
if menu == 3:
    ced = input("Ingrese Cedula a Consultar del paciente: ")

    obj_paciente = None
    for paciente in lst:
        if ced == paciente.cedula:
            obj_paciente = paciente
            break
    else:
        print("Paciente no encontrado")

    if obj_paciente:
        mod = int(input("Escriba 1 si desea modificar este elemento: "))
        if mod == 1:
            obj_paciente.nombre = input("ingrese Nuevo Nombre: ")
```

o directamente:

```
if menu == 3:
    ced = input("Ingrese Cedula a Consultar del paciente: ")

    for paciente in lst:
        if ced == paciente.cedula:
            mod = int(input("Escriba 1 si desea modificar este elemento: "))
            if mod == 1:
                paciente.nombre = input("ingrese Nuevo Nombre: ")
            break
    else:
        print("Paciente no encontrado")
```

Por ejemplo:

```
class Paciente:
    def __init__(self, cod, name, lastname, dni, bornDate):
        self.codigo = cod
        self.nombre = name
        self.apellido = lastname
        self.cedula = dni
        self.FechaNacimiento = bornDate

lst = [Paciente(0, "Pedro", "Martínez", "45217458Z", "10/11/1985"),
       Paciente(1, "Luis", "García", "68866866A", "25/04/1975"),
       Paciente(2, "Laura", "Aquilera", "5599664T", "09/07/1990"),
       Paciente(3, "María", "Zamora", "65656566H", "17/03/2005")
      ]


menu = 3

if menu == 3:
    ced = input("Ingrese Cedula a Consultar del paciente: ")

    for paciente in lst:
        if ced == paciente.cedula:
            mod = int(input("Escriba 1 si desea modificar este elemento: "))
            if mod == 1:
                paciente.nombre = input("ingrese Nuevo Nombre: ")
            break
    else:
        print("Paciente no encontrado")
```

> ```
> Ingrese Cedula a Consultar del paciente: 68885669K
> Paciente no encontrado   
>
> ========================================================    
>
> Ingrese Cedula a Consultar del paciente: 68866866A    
> Escriba 1 si desea modificar este elemento: 1    
> ingrese Nuevo Nombre: Juan    
>
> >>> print(lst[1].nombre, lst[1].apellido, lst[1].cedula)     
> Juan García 68866866A
> ```